# How to implement REMenu using Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, drop-down-menu, implementation

I have two viewControllers.
How to implement [REMenu](https://github.com/romaonthego/REMenu) using storyboard ?
Where to put this implementation, how to load another view controller ?

```
REMenuItem *homeItem = [[REMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home"
                                                  subtitle:@"Return to Home Screen"
                                                     image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon_Home"]
                                          highlightedImage:nil
                                                    action:^(REMenuItem *item) {
                                                        NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
                                                    }];

REMenuItem *exploreItem = [[REMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Explore"
                                                   subtitle:@"Explore 47 additional options"
                                                      image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon_Explore"]
                                           highlightedImage:nil
                                                     action:^(REMenuItem *item) {
                                                         NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
                                                     }];


self.menu = [[REMenu alloc] initWithItems:@[homeItem, exploreItem]];
[self.menu showFromNavigationController:self.navigationController];
```